# How do you parse large files in Groovy without exceeding heap size?

Tags: groovy

When parsing a large file I get the following error `Caught: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`

How do you parse large files in Groovy without exceeding heap size?

example code that fails with large files...

```
import java.io.File

def inputFile = new File("c:/dev/test.txt")
    inputFile.getText().eachLine{ it, i ->
            ... do something with each line
        }
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ensure that the you're iterating over the file in a way that doesn't load the whole file into memory...

- In this case specifically turn **inputFile.getText().eachLine** into **inputFile.eachLine**
- Don't use **.readLines()** as it will try and load the whole file into memory, .**eachLine{..}** should be used instead
- You can also extend the heap size with a jvm flag, eg to 1GB by using `groovy -Xmx1024M myscript.groovy` See also [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5459317/how-do-i-increase-groovys-jvm-heap-size)

See this [page](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/Reading-the-contents-of-a-File-without-impacting-heap-space-Reading-the-file-into-memory-td4582259.html) on the groovy mailing list for more info and further discussion

Code that works without a heap space error...

```
def inputFile = new File("c:/dev/test.txt")
inputFile.eachLine{ it, i ->
        ... do something with each line
    }
```

Comment: This is okay as long as it's not one massive line. It can boil down to what he/she intends to do with the data.